# Save todos in localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I've created a todo app, and I want to save the todo's in `localStorage`.

I was thinking to add the `localStorage` property like this:

```
addForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let todo = addForm.add.value.trim();
    if (todo.length) {
        localStorage.setItem(todo);
        generateTemplate(todo);
        addForm.reset();
    }
}
```

But, it's not working.

So, my question is, in which part of the code is it best practice to add the property and in which part is it best to also add the `getItem` method?

---

Here is the whole code without the `localStorage` property:

```js
const addForm = document.querySelector(".add");
const list = document.querySelector(".todos");
const search = document.querySelector(".search input");

// generate new toDo's
const generateTemplate = (todo) => {
  let html = ` <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <span>${todo}</span><i class="far fa-trash-alt delete"></i>
  </li>`;
  list.innerHTML += html;
};

// submit the todo
addForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let todo = addForm.add.value.trim();
  if (todo.length) {
    generateTemplate(todo);
    addForm.reset();
  }
});

// delete todo's

list.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("delete")) {
    e.target.parentElement.remove();
  }
});

// filter the toDo's

const filterTodos = (term) => {
  Array.from(list.children)
    .filter((todo) => !todo.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(term))
    .forEach((todo) => todo.classList.add("filtered"));

  Array.from(list.children)
    .filter((todo) => todo.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(term))
    .forEach((todo) => todo.classList.remove("filtered"));
};

search.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
  const term = search.value.trim().toLowerCase();
  filterTodos(term);
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #352f5b;
}

.container {
  max-width: 400px;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="text"]:focus {
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 400px;
}

.todos li {
  background: #423a6f;
}

.delete {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.filtered {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>toDoList</title>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fa5117c01c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header class="text-center text-light my-4">
      <h1 class="text-ligth mb.4">thingsToDo</h1>
      <form action="" class="search"><input type="text" class="form-control m-auto" name="search" placeholder="Search toDo's"></form>
    </header>
    <ul class="list-group todos mx-auto text-light"></ul>
    <form class="add text-center my-4">
      <label class="text-light">Add new toDo...</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control m-auto" name="add">
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

Storages object (what you use with LocalStorage) allows to save Strings (DOMStrings to be specific), so if you want to save a javascript object, you should convert it to string first (eg. with [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify))

On your code, also, the syntax for `setItem` is incorrect. You need to specify [a key that identifies the object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```js
   localStorage.setItem('todo', todo);
```

Notice that this will only save a todo. Therefore, when you get todo's back you will need to do `localStorage.getItem('todo')` and this of course will only return the last todo that you have saved.

A solution for this might be to have a storage for your todos:

```js
var todos = []
```

Everytime you create a new todo you add that todo to this object

```js
todos.push(todo)
```

and saves it to localstorage

```js
localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos))
```

When you get back that list, you will need to [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) the string back to get the actual object:

```js
var todosString = localStorage.getItem('todos');
var todos = JSON.parse(todosString);
```

Take into account that this will only get your todos data into that var. Then you need to repopulate your dom.
This can be done by reusing your `generateTemplate` function.
Eg.

```js
todos.forEach(todo => generateTemplate(todo));
```

I'd also recommend you to take a look at the MDN page for LocalStorage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

And the Using the Web Storage API page for a full working example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, I really undertsand the point. but there is still a problem, every time I refresh the page I lose all the info of the list

Comment: That's because you need to read it from the storage and build the list on the reload. (Local)Storage only saves data, it doens't know anything about your app. You should have some piece of code that reads from local storage and add the todos

Comment: I have expanded on that at the end of the answer